# Colocar um IF dentro do texto HTML com ionic/firebase

Tags: ionic, firebase

então estou com um problema no meu codigo, eu gostaria de fazer um if dentro do meu codigo html do ionic, algo como:

```
<ion-item class="camposSelect" *ngFor="let person of profiles" >
        <ion-label color="primary">Dia: </ion-label>
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="ficha.teste" required >
            <ion-option [value]="person.DiaCriado">{{person.DiaCriado >= 17 ? 'person.DiaCriado' : ' '}}</ion-option>


        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```

Por conta que dentro do meu banco há a pesquisa desse node, eu gostaria que se a afirmação fosse verdadeira ele exibesse todos os campos que  sao maiores que 17,porém estou com dois erros, o primeiro é que se a afirmação for verdadeira ele esta me mostrnado "person.DiaCriado" e não o valor que esta no banco, e segundo que se for falsa, ele esta me mostrando um option vazio, eu gostaria que ele nem aparecesse.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazer algo do tipo.

```
<ion-item class="camposSelect" *ngFor="let person of profiles" >
    <ion-label color="primary">Dia: </ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="ficha.teste" required >
        <ion-option [value]="person.DiaCriado" *ngIf="person.DiaCriado >= 17">
          {{ person.DiaCriado }}
        </ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Acho que isso deve resolver.

**Obs**: Seu primeiro erro é que o `person.DiaCriado` está entre `''`, basta tirar, o segundo realmente irá exibir um `select` com valor `' '`, pois foi a condição colocada, realmente acho que a melhor solução é o `if`, no caso você usaria o `*ngIf`

Comment: Muito Obrigado, a resposta serviu perfeitamente.

Comment: Precisando, estamos ai :D